# Excel 2013 wont let me save XLSX files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, file-types

So, just recently when I tried to save an excel (.xlsx) file in Excel 2013, I got the following error message:

[image]

I have not changed my file block settings in the trust center however.    Here is a screenshot of my settings in the trust center.

[image]

As you can see, I do not have any file types set to be blocked from opening or saving!   I have never encountered this issue before in Excel, and was wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this issue?    I am an administrator on the computer I am having this issue on, I own MS Office 2013 Professional and my copy is registered, and I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.   I am not on a windows domain.   Please help!  Let me know if you need any further details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh, so I guess if something is checked in file block settings, that means to block it.   Uncheck the item to unblock it.   Problem resolved.